# Is this star group a constellation recognized by the IAU?

Tags: constellations

Below is an arrangement of stars I've found in a TV series. As an amateur astronomer I cannot identify if this is a constellation, after having looked through what is recognized by the IAU. Is this just a depiction of a random group of stars?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried submitting it to the [astrometry.net online solver](http://nova.astrometry.net/) and see if it can identify it ?

Comment: Which TV series/episode?

Comment: http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/3531082 No calibration.

Comment: Thanks for uploading it @JamesK, it was a worth a try...

Comment: @MikeG Sex Education, season 2, episode 8, at the every end of the episode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IAU recognizes 88 constellations. The charts for each constellation can be found at the [bottom of this page from the IAU website](https://www.iau.org/public/themes/constellations/). You can go through them yourself, but I haven't found any that really resembles your image. So it probably isn't a constellation recognized by the IAU.

But it could still be part of the sky, without being a constellation. So I also ran the image through [astrometry.net](http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/3532714#original), but it didn't find what field the image could belong to.

This suggests that it is just a random group of stars, rather than an actual image of the sky.